# Typical erlang web/enterprise application architecture?

Tags: architecture, frameworks, erlang

Is there a web app framework written in erlang?
How common is to use erlang for building web apps? 
Is there a recommended app stack. Erlang, CouchDB,....,?

Comment: There's [Erlyweb](http://erlyweb.org/) but it seems to be asleep ...

Comment: also [Erlang Web](http://www.erlang-web.org/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course there is. E.g. see [WebMachine](http://webmachine.basho.com/), [Erlyweb](http://erlyweb.org/), [Nitrogen](http://nitrogenproject.com/) et al.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, the best erlang web framework is [Chicago Boss](http://www.chicagoboss.org/).
It has MVC architecture and many things like in Rails. It also has fully support of MySQL, MongoDB, PostgreSQL. Chicago Bos has builtin comet server.
There is [comparison](http://www.chicagoboss.org/projects/chicagoboss/wiki/Comparison_of_Erlang_Web_Frameworks) of erlang web frameworks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating something that looks like an API, use [webmachine](http://webmachine.basho.com/). It's a fantastic project - I use it at work to create large scale ad feeds.

If you need something that looks like a UI, you should check out [nitrogen](http://nitrogenproject.com/), and [chicago boss](http://www.chicagoboss.org/). I have used nitrogen on a couple of small projects, but as of this writing I have not tried CB. CB seems to look a lot like rails - MVC, DB support built in, and some magic to glue it all together. Nitrogen uses an event-driven model, has tightly integrated Ajax support, and does not provide a DB layer.

Your choice of DB should obviously be driven by the needs of your project. There are drivers for most everything: mysql, redis, mongo, etc. I'm personally a big fan of [riak](http://wiki.basho.com/) for a number of reasons, but chiefly because of its master-less replication and pluggable backends.

Comment: Thanks for thorough explanation

Answer (score 1):

See [Nitrogen Web Framework](http://nitrogenproject.com/)